# Show the rest of the users you can ping in chat when there are too many to display at one time

Tags: feature-request, chat, users, ping

I have recently noticed that when there are more than a certain amount of people with a similar name you get this

[image]

However it is not very clear at all who the other people not listed are... So I think that it would be very good if maybe when you <kbd>TAB</kbd> beyond it for it to show you the rest in the same format as it shows you the others, and then if you <kbd>TAB</kbd> beyond those, you'll either get to the next 'page', or back to the beginning again.
Or at least something like this would be useful, because currently, unless you try adding on all the different letters after the `@S`, it is almost impossible to tell who the other matches are...